# Passing a pointer to a function as a parameter - C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, typedef

I have a list of functions from which the user chooses one to be used. This function is then passed as a parameter for some other function.
For example:

```
// Declare some functions here

int main() {
    // Declare some pointer
    int choice;
    cout << "1 - functionA, 2 - functionB..." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
        case 1:
        // Assign pointer to functionA address
        break;
        case 2: //etc
        // Assign pointer to functionB address
        break;
        //etc
    }
    float x; float y; float z;
    float value = BigFunc(//ChosenFunction, x, y, z);
    cout << value << endl;
    return 0;
}

float BigFunc(//ChosenFunction(returns a float), float x, float y, float z) {
    // Some code
    float a = OtherFunc(//ChosenFunction, x, y, z);
    // Some code
    return a;
}

float OtherFunc(//ChosenFunction, float x, float y, float z) {
    for (//some for loop) {
    return b += ChosenFunction(x);
    }
    return b;
}
```

I have used comments to indicate areas where some code would be. The functions from which the user can choose are functions which take 1 float argument, perform some mathematical operations on that value and then return it.

I have seen some examples online however they are all very specific and have not helped me very much. I have tried to keep the example in this post as general as possible so that hopefully others that stumble across it can learn from it too.

I have attempted to use pointers to accomplish this task however it has been to no avail. Online I have seen people using `float (*pointer)(float)` however I am unfamiliar with using a pointer like this. I have also seen people using `typedef` however once again I am unsure of how to implement that here.

Any help or pointers (pun) in the right direction would be much appreciated!
Sean.

*Edit: The question which this has been tagged as a duplicate of is similar however I did look at that question before and I felt that it does not sufficiently resolve this problem. The program which I am writing is more complicated than this case however I have kept it simpler so that others can find this post helpful after I am finished with it.*

Comment: Why do you want to use function pointers here at all? Just calling them directly from the `case` blocks in the switch would do fine here?

Comment: Also note that the signature of your function pointer seems to need looking like this `float (*pointer)(float,float,float)`

Comment: I suggested this as a duplicate since the accepted answer there illustrates the usage of function pointers, and how their types are declared. If you're after something more specific, you should edit your question to reflect that.